# Text pushing sibling elements down in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I'm coding a script that will populate an area with circles of portraits and slogans scattered here and there. I've managed to place the elements neatly side by side except in Internet Explorer. I'm using IE9 so in theory, it should work but doesn't.

I've tried everything I can think of but nothing seems to work. I'm hoping someone here has a better idea than me on how to beat IE at this.

JSFiddle demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/TnUxt/

HTML code:

```
<div class='wrapper'>
<ul>
<div class='row'>
    <li class='dataLi'>
        <a href='' class='fancybox'>
            <div class='overlay'>
                <div class='circle' style="background:url(http://bit.ly/Z9CY5A) no-repeat;background-size: cover"></div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class='dataLi'>
        <a href=''>
            <div class='circle slogan'>test</div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class='dataLi'>
        <a href='' class='fancybox'>
            <div class='overlay'>
                <div class='circle' style="background:url(http://bit.ly/ULb3ux) no-repeat;background-size: cover"></div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
</div>

<div class='row'>
    <li class='dataLi'>
        <a href='' class='fancybox'>
            <div class='overlay'>
                <div class='circle' style="background:url(http://bit.ly/XVpxN5) no-repeat;background-size: cover"></div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class='dataLi'>
        <a href=''>
            <div class='circle slogan'>test</div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class='dataLi'>
        <a href='' class='fancybox'>
            <div class='overlay'>
                <div class='circle' style="background:url(http://bit.ly/15Wl5gM) no-repeat;background-size: cover"></div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
</div>
</ul>
```

CSS code:

```
.wrapper {
width: 700px;
height: 1000px;
margin: 0 auto;
border: 1px solid black;
}
.row {
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
}
.circle {
background: #d9d6d1;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
border-radius: 50%;
-moz-border-radius: 50%;
-webkit-border-radius: 50%;
opacity:1;
filter:alpha(opacity=100);
vertical-align: top;
display: inline-block;
*zoom: 1;
*display: inline;
}
.circle:hover {
opacity: 0.5;
filter:alpha(opacity=50);
background: #fd761f;
}
.slogan {
background:#fd761f;
color: #fff;
text-align: center;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 200px;
vertical-align: top;
display: inline-block;
*zoom: 1;
*display: inline;
}
.overlay:hover {
background:#fd761f;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
border-radius: 50%;
-moz-border-radius: 50%;
-webkit-border-radius: 50%;
}
ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
li {
list-style-type: none;
display: inline-block;
*zoom: 1;
*display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution would be to apply a `float:left;` to either the `.circle` or `.slogan` classes. This will pull the text content out of its context and position the circles appropriately.

http://jsfiddle.net/TnUxt/1/

Answer (score 0):

If I increase the line-height, the orange circles move up. However, finding a remedy that gives a good & cross-browser result is severely hampered by the fact that you have put <div>s inside <a>s. Block elements or inline-block elements inside inline elements, that is too tricky.

If you could correct that, I'll be happy to have a further look.